# Convert line to specific keyboard character

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
   <tr>
     <td width="100%" bgcolor="#96002D" height="3" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
```

It's just a line, but I want to replace line for "/" character so I get something like:

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

How can I do that?

I try these:

```
  <tr>
   <td align="center">////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////</td>
                </tr>
```

But I think it can be more useful like that

Comment: What exactly your requirement?

Comment: just change line for "/" character with inline-style  with width= 100% @akhilviswam

Comment: I edit my try but is to noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do exactly what you want but here are 3 alternatives that might help you.

**1. Will look different to how you want, but the simplest option**

`border: 3px solid dashed;` in the `<td>`.

**2. What you are after but a bit of a hack**

set the `<td>` to 
`overflow: hidden;`
 and within it add a 
`<p style="white-space:nowrap;>///</p>` (with enough '/'s that it will always exceed the width of the `<td>`.

**3. Also close to what you are after, but you will need to create a .png image of the '/' character**

add a `background-image` of the '/' character as a .png for the `<td>` and set `background-repeat: repeat-y;`.